# Create Static Arrays using php Sample code

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Aries
            [id] => 1
        )
```

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => Taurus
        [id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => Gemini
        [id] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [value] => Cancer
        [id] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [value] => Leo
        [id] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [value] => Virgo
        [id] => 6
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [value] => Libra
        [id] => 7
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [value] => Scorpio
        [id] => 8
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [value] => Sagittarius
        [id] => 9
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [value] => Capricorn
        [id] => 10
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [value] => Aquarius
        [id] => 11
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [value] => Pisces
        [id] => 12
    )
```

)

I tried the following code

$data = array
      (
      array( "value" => "Aries","id"=>"1"),
      array("value" => "Taurus","id"=>"2"),
      array("value" => "Gemini","id"=>"3"),
      array("value" => "Cancer","id"=>"4"),
      array("value" => "Leo","id"=>"5"),
      array("value" => "Virgo","id"=>"6"),
      array("value" => "Libra","id"=>"7"),
      array("value" => "Scorpio","id"=>"8"),
      array("value" => "Sagittarius","id"=>"9"),
      array("value" => "Capricorn","id"=>"10"),
      array("value" => "Aquarius","id"=>"11"),
      array("value" => "Pisces","id"=>"12"),

`);`

And i got perfect output.But i don't know this is a good way or not?Is this a good way?or please give me a good solution.I am totally beginner in php.

Comment: As an array definition it looks perfectly fine to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing to ask about here, its a normal way to create arrays in php, but if you don't want to get your hands dirty with filling in this array, especially it has too many typical and repeated data, you can create a one-dimensional array for the names, then make a loop to create the `$data` array, as follow:

```
$names = array("Aries","Taurus", etc...);

$data = array();

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($names); $i++){
   $temp["value"] = $names[$i];
   $temp["id"] = $i+1;
   $data[] = $temp;
}
```